# Issues when opening a pickle file created in python 2.7

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, pickle

I have several pickle files compiled wiht Python 2.7 that are readable with pandas in Python 3.11 however there's one that has won't load. This is the part of the code where I'm facing issues:

```
import json
import pickle
import pandas as pd

with open('path', 'rb') as f:
    data = pickle.load(f)
```

With the following error:

```
  import pandas as pd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path", line 7, in <module>
    data = pickle.load(f)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/copyreg.py", line 49, in _reconstructor
    obj = object.__new__(cls)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: object.__new__(BlockManager) is not safe, use BlockManager.__new__()
```

I read it's an issue regarding the version of pandas used when the pickle file was created but nothing I've tried worked and I wonder if the file is just corrupted.

I have tried:

1. Running the script on a virtual instance with Python 2.7 but I get some errors with pandas, mentioning it wasn't working correctly.
2. Using online pickle to json converter.
3. Update pandas and update pip.
   Also tried the following options to read a pickle:
   `joblib.load(path)`
   `pd.read_pickle(path)`
   No option has allowed me to read the pickle file.

Comment: The issue is that `pickle.dump()` actually dumps all the bytecode that makes up the data, including object instantiation, which are different between Python-2.7 and Python-3. Is it possible to open the pickle file using Python-2.7 and save it as, say, JSON or YAML instead?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```py
import pandas as pd

with open('path_to_pickle_file', 'rb') as f:
    data = pd.read_pickle(f)

data.to_csv('path_to_csv_file.csv', index=False)

data = pd.read_csv('path_to_csv_file.csv')
```

Comment: I ran that code in Python 2.7 and the output csv is missing several variables. I also tried saving it as YAML but I get ConstructorError when reading it on Python 3.11. `ConstructorError: could not determine a constructor for the tag 'tag:yaml.org,2002:python/unicode'`